# Leading for SourceSerifPro

Tags: fonts

[Edited]

Are there any fans of SourceSerifPro here? I'm using it, and am thinking it needs a little extra space between the lines than what my software selects by default (11/13.6 pt), but I don't have an eye for such things (not a designer nor a typographer).

Any advice? What seemed to look good to me was a considerable bump from 13.6 pt, which makes me hesitant. Many of the comments are of the nature of "do whatever you think best", but I doubt anyone would give such advice to an intern doing work for a paying customer. Experienced judgement has value.

I'm using this font for class handouts printed on letter paper, with a fairly wide line that averages about 80 characters per line (about 5 3/8 inches).

I've lengthened my examples and provided them in a context showing the actual width of my text block. (Unfortunately, unless your monitor is larger than mine, the site shrinks the image in order to fit it.) I also labeled them in absolute units, since that seems less confusing.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!  Could you share a screenshot of what you have now so we can take a look?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GDSE! When you talk about "extra" line spacing it makes me think you might be using Microsoft Word? Word talks about "single" and "double" line space. In professional layout programs the line spacing (or leading) is measured in a physical dimension. Often *points* like the font size. A graphic designer wouldn't hesitate to manually choose a line spacing since no line spacing is really considered "default".

Comment: If you’ve got wide lines with ~80 characters per line, I’d probably go for what would be around 15%, at a guess. Around 11/15.5–16 or so. 11/14 is generally a pretty good rule-of-thumb basis for medium-length lines in body text, but you’ll need more if your lines are longer.

Comment: I've never heard of line spacing defined in %. Is it commonly accepted that 10/12 (or whatever number you are working with here) is the "default"?

Comment: @Wolff, Latex has default line spacing for three font sizes: 10/12, 11/13.6 and 12/14.5. "Default" in the sense that if you select an 11pt font, you automatically get 13.6pt spacing unless you explicitly change it. It's not important, the question boils down to what line spacing should I use with 11pt SourceSerifPro, given fairly wide lines.

Comment: There are no rules. Use what you feel looks best and allows readers to easily track the next line.

Comment: @user1984717, when you talk about +10% line spacing it's important to know what you consider the default or it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Scott I don't have an eye for this stuff, so I'm asking for opinions.

Comment: @user1984717 - I don't think there is anything wrong with any of these. My advice would be choose what you like. If you think it needs a little extra space, then do it.

Comment: @user1984717 Can you show screenshots of a whole page with each of the linespreads so we can see how big your margins are etc. ?

Comment: @user1984717 Opinions aren't what stack exchange sites are about. How on Earth can you choose a "correct" answer if everything is merely *opinion*?

Comment: When _opinion_ is based on experienced judgement, it is useful. And that which is useful can be _correct_ in some sense. (A _useful_ sense!) Not everything is math and science, some fields are art.

I'll try get a more extensive example up tonight.

Comment: Funny.. don't think I've seen a new user tout how design is art `:)` I wasn't suggesting this was science or math, just the opposite.--  If I were to post an answer that I prefer 140% leading most of the time... and someone else with equal experience posts that they prefer 160% leading... how would you choose a **correct** answer other than whichever one you *happen* to agree with? How is that helpful to *any* future visitor? -- As I commented.. use whatever YOU feel is apprpriate and allows users to easily track the next line.

Comment: I agree with @Scott that as it is this question will not provide anything else than opinions because the given 3 examples are all valid options which lies within the "norm". In different settings they can be equally good. OTOH I also agree with the OP that a professional's opinion can be *qualified* and I would love to see more in-depth questions on this site about typography. It can't be true that everything about typography is just "a matter of opinion" and "not science". The tricky part is how to ask those questions ...

Comment: I like 11/15 pt.

Comment: .. and I tend to set sales copy for the <=40 demographic at 11/16 older demos at 12/17 or 12/18 `:)`